# Ошибка при открытии JSON файла

Tags: php

Есть следующий класс

```
class Json {
    private $file; 
    private $json;

    function __construct() {
        $this->$file = __DIR__ . '\..\file.json';
        $this->$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($this->$file));
    }

    public function change($namespace, $object, $value) {
        $this->$json->$namespace->$object->text = $value;
        $f = fopen($this->$file, 'w');
        fputs($f, json_encode($this->$json));
        fclose($f);
        return true;
    }
}
```

При вызове функции change

```
$JSON = new Json();
$JSON->change('section', 'par', 'value');
```

Появляются ошибки

*Warning: fopen() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, object given in json.php on line 14*

*Warning: fputs() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in json.php on line 15*

*Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in json.php on line 16*

Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К нестатическим свойствам внутри класса следует обращаться так: `$this->file`, `$this->json` (без знака $ перед именем).

```
class Json {
    private $file; 
    private $json;

    function __construct() {
        $this->file = __DIR__ . '\..\file.json';
        $this->json = json_decode(file_get_contents($this->file));
    }

    public function change($namespace, $object, $value) {
        $this->json->$namespace->$object->text = $value;
        file_put_contents($this->file, json_encode($this->json));
        return true;
    }
}
```